# Correct procedure for JSON parsing in Rails/Jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a json string that if I paste in a validator says it is valid. When I look in the console it is valid.

But yet I cannot get JQuery to parse $.parseJSON returns null, and I am not sure what is wrong?

```
    console.log(<%= @data_array_as_json.to_s.html_safe%>);
    var data = $.parseJSON(<%= @data_array_as_json.to_s.html_safe %>);
    console.log("Results of parse: "+data);
```

Can someone please help this is seriously holding my back on a time sensitive assessment,.

Answer (score 0):

This took me so long messing about.. and no one provided any feedback.

In case someone else gets in this situation and can figure out what is wrong..

Here is the solution:
var data = $.parseJSON('<%= @data_array_as_json.to_s.html_safe %>');

I needed the '' inside the brackets.